# Psycopg2 not empty result unless WHERE clause hard coded

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I'm trying to do a very basic query with psycopg2 but it doesn't give me a result unless I hardcode the parameter, what am I doing wrong? Might be that I'm having midnight-brain here but I don't think so...

This doesn't work:

```
query = """SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM symbol) as symbol, timestamp, open, close, high, low, volume
                FROM trades_1_min
                WHERE symbol=%(symbol)s
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"""
with db_conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query, {'symbol': symbol})
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return res
return None
```

Whereas if I put quotes around the input [... symbol='%(symbol)s' ...] I can see that it's actually putting the query parameter there because I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testlol.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "testlol.py", line 20, in main
    print(get_latest("amd"))
  File "testlol.py", line 12, in get_latest
    cursor.execute(query, {'symbol': symbol})
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "amd"
LINE 3:                 WHERE symbol=''amd''
```

Now, if I simply run the query in psql I get the answer. And yes, I am connected to the correct database, with the correct user etc. An ever simpler query worked to confirm that.

```
import psycopg2

db_conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="pi", user="pi", password="raspberry")

def lol():
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM trades_1_min LIMIT 1')
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    print(res)

def get_latest(symbol):
    query = """SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM symbol) as symbol, timestamp, open, close, high, low, volume
            FROM trades_1_min
            WHERE symbol=%(symbol)s
            ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"""
    with db_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query, {'symbol': symbol})
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return res
    return None


def main():
    lol()
    #print(get_latest("amd"))

main()
```

And here's the table structure:
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8H86.png)

Comment: The function `get_latest` is returning `None` so `print(get_latest("amd"))` would return `None`. You see something when you quote the parameter because it throws an exception before it gets to `return None` and you see the value in the traceback.

Comment: But it doesn't return None, it returns an empty list.

Comment: @Joel Andersson: `get_latest` will not work due to a syntax error, what's wrong with the first query ?

Comment: What's the syntax error? The first query (in the lol() function is merely to show that there's nothing wrong with the database connection).

Comment: I cannot replicate. Creating a similar function here works. The only thing I could not replicate was the `symbol` value being passed in. Are you sure it was you think its is and/or there are not case differences involved in `WHERE symbol=%(symbol)s`?  I have solved these problems by cranking up `log_statement` to `'all'` and seeing what query looks like when it hits the server. This generates a lot of logs so you don't want to leave it that way long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I was having was really quite stupid. My symbols were stored in capital letters. So I was asking for 'amd' but I only had 'AMD', so quite logically it didn't find anything... So it was indeed a case of the midnight-brains.